# WSL2 kali-win-kex always launches desktop in seamless mode

Tags: windows, kali-linux, wsl2

I've managed to successfully install Kali with WSL2 on a Windows 11 home machine. I've also managed to install (and reinstall) kali-win-kex. `kex --win -s` works as expected, but when I run

```
$ kex --sl -s
```

Two things happen: A Kali panel appears at the top of my Windows desktop as expected, but then a Kali (gnome) desktop immediately launches afterward and covers the Windows desktop.

The output (within Kali) from the command to run Kex in seamless is:

```
Starting Win-KeX server (SL)
        Unable to find Win-KeX server (SL) running on host: 172.24.0.1  Win-KeX server (SL) stopped
        Win-KeX server (SL) is stopped
Starting Win-KeX client (SL)
        Unable to find Win-KeX server (SL) running on host: 172.24.0.1  Enabling Win-KeX client (SL)

        xfDesktop started after 3 seconds
        Enabling transparency now


        Saving Win-KeX server (SL) session
        Started Win-KeX server (SL)
```

How can I configure Kex or Kali to work correctly in seamless?